# JQuery Mobile DateBox Calender Close Button

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am using JQuery Mobile DateBox Calendar dialog.

My problem is that the Calendar popup has no close button.

Any idea of how I could get the close button to show please?

Thanks

Comment: I never used it but i took a quick read at the documentation and seems that you only need to click outside the widget to close it unless you have the option **forceInput** = true afaik it doesnt have a close button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the force dialog option I believe it has the close button option

Look under the **Advanced Options Demo**

Also looks like the developer has added a bunch of new functionality as well:

http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox/

Answer (score 1):

Can you give the calling code? Assuming it's done in an input field, you could give it an ID and make a button:

```
<input type='submit' title='Close date picker' onclick='function() { $(#dateboxid).hide;}'>
```